# DNS registrar - Not all the people in china can reach my site

Tags: domain-name-system, godaddy, amazon-route53, resolve, china

I have some websites on the cloud (Rackspace for that matter), and I manage their DNS using Route53 (the domain is registered on GoDaddy if it matters).

The thing is that those websites are targeted to the Chinese community, and we know that some of them are able to see those sites, while some of them don't.

Checking the PC's that can't reach the site shows that they don't get the URL's from their DNS provider. Changing the DNS to 8.8.8.8 solved the issue.

Off course i can't change the DNS settings of a billion people, but **is there any way to manage my DNS in a China's friendly DNS registrar instead of route 53?** (or in addition?).

Comment: Dns propagation is sometime very very slow . you can google that to find 'dns propagation checker' . (this one for example www.whatsmydns.net)

Comment: Yes, google (8.8.) / CloudFlare (1.1.) and others are very quick to update - especially off route53 records. So, it's probably just a matter of waiting it out for smaller ones to catch up. But, do keep in mind that the CN govt has ultimate control on whether ppl see a site, or their dns resolver used 'works' properly. This may be of value, too - https://www.usenix.org/node/217554

Answer (score 1):

I personally use [CloudFlare](http://www.cloudflare.com) , they have their own data centres worldwide and they have the facility of DNS caching. Try it and will resolve your problem. consider propagation before changing name servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the DNS services of other China targeted websites using. As an example, [Pacificidc](https://pacificidc.com/) is a company which is targeted to Chinese users, and they use CloudFlare's DNS system. You might want to try it out or check other DNS systems that China targeted websites use.